# Visual Studio 2008 breakpoint is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I am working on an ASP.NET project and I cannot make the breakpoints work! 
The project does not stop where I place a breakpoint. It does not seem to 
matter where I place the breakpoint.

I am in debug mode; I am using IE 8, Windows 7 OS;

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Comment: are you using the VS Dev server or IIS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my experience, BEFORE you hit F5 to debug, do a BUILD & and ReBuild. Then hit F5 and that should work (9 out of 10 times) !!

HTH

Answer (score 1):

is Debug set to true in the web.config as well as the build mode?

```
<compilation debug="true">
```

Comment: Good point. on XP machines running VS2008, the .NEt breakpoints were NOT hit when this setting was FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Did You:
1) Run the program in debug mode such that VS auto-attaches to the process as it loads?
*or*

2) Attach manually to the ASP.NET worker process that is already running via Debug..Attach to Process ?

3) Did you set debug="true" in the <compilation> element of the web.config, ie:
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true">

4) If it is a client-side jscript breakpoint, did you enable script debugging in Tools..Internet Options..Advanced..uncheck both of the "Disabled Script Debugging" checkboxes ?

Post the answers to these and then can follow up with more help

Comment: I am in debug mode;
How do I attach manually to the asp.net worker process?

Comment: Menu: Debug..Attach to Process...
Then look for the worker process in the list, on XP it is named aspnet_wp.exe, on later OS with IIS6+, the process is named w3wp.exe. Make sure when you highlight the process that "Managed code" appears in the "Attach to:" box just above the process list. Then click the Attach button.

Comment: The comment I just posted for attaching only works if you are using IIS, if you are using the local auto-dev web server, then it should be auto attaching when you do Debug..Start Debugging or F5 to run the web app.

Comment: @David, thats my concern, I am using localhost, and it shouldnt be this complicated to run debug locally; I am also on Windows 7 OS;

Comment: can you confirm if you are trying to debug server sides asp.net code or client-side javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE8 then you need to follow these settings

On registery
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main

Put Value:
DWORD TabProcGrowth
Value 0

Comment: afraid to modify the registry;

Comment: are you using IE8 ?
Because in that case, the default feature of IE8 LCIE doesn't allow you to debug.

Just need to change the value, i have tried it, it works fine.

Comment: I don't have access to modify the registry;